# iOS crash : Unable to open a realm at Path

Tags: ios, realm

I am seeing a number of crashes on Crashlytics but unable to reproduce the the crash which is happening on app launch. Does anyone know how to reproduce the below crash. I have tried all the answers on Github and stackoverflow and no one has mentioned about reproducing this specific crash. 
So if i do have a fix there is no way to test it except putting the fix in production and then assuming Crashlytics wont show crashes.

Please help.

**Error:**

`Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/03BA7C37-9852-4A01-8EF6-949E308EADCD/Documents/default.realm.lock': open() failed: Operation not permitted." UserInfo={Error Code=2, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/03BA7C37-9852-4A01-8EF6-949E308EADCD/Documents/default.realm.lock,`

calling code

```
//passing the fileProtectionType as .none
RealmHelper.configureRealmFiles(with: .none)
```

Sample code

```
   static func configureRealmFiles(with fileProtectionType: FileProtectionType) {
            guard let folderPath = realm.configuration.fileURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().path else {
                return
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.protectionKey: fileProtectionType],
                                                      ofItemAtPath: folderPath)
            } catch {
                logI("Realm: Couldn't change Realm file protection type")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried turning off sandboxing if it's on? Select the project int he left column, then Capabilities tab->Sandboxing.

Comment: Please share your code. Especially the one where you use `Realm` on app start.

Comment: @Václav i have updated the question to have the code. Is there a way to replicate the crash itself to understand when does this happens ?

Comment: lol. I know that. That's why I was asking if your *tried it* with sandboxing off.

Comment: @Jay how will i turn off the sandboxing for iOS app project if it's not available for me to change ? also I have not done this. Also is it ok to have the sandbox turned off when you release the app to appstore ? Also my question is more on how do replicate this crash if you can help on that as well.

Comment: @Jay thanks as i said i tried turn off the sandboxing option, but the option is not available in capabilities tab of my project so i cannot turn it off.

Comment: Ah! you are building iOS App... The Sandbox feature is macOS, sorry, I forgot about that.

Comment: does anyone has solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the default.realm.lock in a new location did the trick and stops the crashes from appearing again. However I was never able to replicate the crash. This is because it could be happening in background.

Comment: can you explain more it.

Answer (score 0):

[Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-realm-with-background-app-refresh) has some information on how to handle this this error. Check if their instructions to downgrade file access attribute is suitable for your case.

Comment: I am using the FileManager.default.setAttributes and passing the fileProtectionType to .none will that be a issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete realm pod from project and reinstall it helped me :)

Comment: What if something is already in production and live then using my suggested solution works.